# Join product_collection with order_item_collection

Tags: module, orders, product-collection, magento1.9.3.7

I am trying to list the most recently ordered products for a custom module (Magento 1.9.3.7).

I have it working, but I believe that the code is less efficient than it could be + the ordering of the products are not by the date of last purchase, which would be ideal.

I imagine that I could just join the products collection onto the 6 most recently sold items, but can't quite make this work. Is there a way to achieve this in one query?

```
$itemsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection');

$itemsCollection
->getSelect()
->limit(6)
->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
->columns('product_id')
->group('product_id')
->join('catalog/product','`main_table`.`product_id` = `catalog/product`.`entity_id`')
->order('MAX(`main_table`.created_at) DESC');

$productids = [];
foreach($itemsCollection as $item) {
    $productids[] = $item->getProductId();
}

$productsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addIdFilter($productids)
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addUrlRewrite()
->addMinimalPrice()
->addFinalPrice();
```

Br,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly within a joined collection but you could do something like this (which in my opinion would have a much better readability than any fancy join-construct):

```
$orderedProductIds = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->setOrder('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->setPageSize(6)
    ->getColumnValues('product_id'); // simply gives you an array of latest ordered product Ids

$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addIdFilter($orderedProductIds)
    ->addUrlRewrite()
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addFinalPrice();


$productCollection->load();

foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    //var_dump($product->getData());
}
```